# Probability calibration with predicted probability & actual outcome in python

Tags: python, calibration

I am reading calibration methods for two days but did not actually make it that how it works. Two types of calibration are there;

1. Platt scaling - prediction space parted into bins & for each bin mean predicted value is plotted against true fraction of positive cases
2. Isotonic regression - Mathematically it tries to fit a weighted least-squares via Quadratic Programming, subject to next observation is always non-decreasing with respect to previous observation.

I have written a python module on calibration based on logistic regression (though I know `LogisticRegression` returns well calibrated predictions by default as it directly optimizes log-loss, I built it to check my understanding)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
from pandas import DataFrame


class logistic_Calibration:
    def __init__(self, data, response):
        self.data = data
        self.response = response

    def Calibration(self):
        Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(self.data, self.response, test_size=0.20, random_state=36)
        logreg = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
        logreg.fit(Xtrain, np.array(ytrain).flatten())
        PredWO_calibration = logreg.predict_proba(Xtest)
        lossWO_calibration = log_loss(ytest, PredWO_calibration)
        clf_sigmoid = CalibratedClassifierCV(logreg, cv=5, method='sigmoid')
        clf_sigmoid.fit(Xtrain, np.array(ytrain).flatten())
        PredWITH_calibration = clf_sigmoid.predict_proba(Xtest)
        lossWITH_calibration = log_loss(ytest, PredWITH_calibration)
        Loss_difference_WO_minus_W = lossWO_calibration - lossWITH_calibration
        return [lossWO_calibration, lossWITH_calibration, Loss_difference_WO_minus_W]
```

But still I am unclear on the following parts,

- How isotonic regression maps the scores to probabilities?
- Platt scaling does not work for real time data as for that we do not have any class assigned, that means Brier score can not be calculated. If after fitting a model, i have predicted probability & actual outcome on training data, how can i use calibration using only these two inputs to assign classes for test data? That is the most important part i would like to know.

Please guide.